# Unexpected indent error in stylus file

Tags: css, stylus

I am getting this weird error with stylus file. No idea why this is coming. Earlier the same stylus used to work. I just tried changing of the margin's value from "margin 20px 10px 0 0" to "margin 20px 10px 10px 0". When I restored the values then too this error is still there.

This is the error

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]!./~/stylus-loader?sourceMap!./src/client/pages/TaggingVideoPage/TestVideoPage.styl
Module build failed: ParseError: unexpected "indent"
    at Parser.error (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:259:11)
    at Parser.stmt (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:819:32)
    at Parser.statement (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:685:21)
    at Parser.block (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:865:21)
    at Parser.selector (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1555:24)
    at Parser.stmt (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:797:27)
    at Parser.statement (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:685:21)
    at Parser.parse (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:236:25)
    at Renderer.render (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus/lib/renderer.js:80:22)
    at /home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/stylus-loader/index.js:163:12
    at tryCatchReject (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:840:30)
    at runContinuation1 (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:799:4)
    at Fulfilled.when (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:590:4)
    at Pending.run (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:481:13)
    at Scheduler._drain (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:62:19)
    at Scheduler.drain (/home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:27:9)
 @ ./src/client/pages/TaggingVideoPage/TestVideoPage.styl 2:18-214 19:6-27:8 20:18-214
```

And this is stylus

```
:local(.container)
    flex 1
    display flex
    overflow scroll

    .left-side, .right-side
        display flex
        flex-direction column
    .left-side
        flex 3

    .right-side
        flex 1.7
        min-width 500px
        flex-shrink 0
        height 100vh



// Components
    .video-player
        padding-left 20px
        padding-right 40px
        padding-bottom 10px
        padding-top 20px
        display block
        width 100%
        .video-el
            max-width 100%

    .video-player-buttons
        padding-left 20px
        padding-right 40px
        padding-bottom 10px
        padding-top 20px
        display flex
        width 100%
        .button-item
            flex 1
            background-color #D7D7D7
            padding 18px 30px
            font-size 1em
            text-align center
            border-radius 8px
            margin 0 4px
            cursor pointer
            &:hover
                background-color darken(@background-color, 10%)

    .video-info
        padding-left 20px
        font-family museo500
        color #4b4b4b
        font-size 34px
        margin-top 5px

    .video-player-tabs
        flex 3
        display flex
        flex-direction column
        margin 20px 10px 0 0
        box-shadow 0px 4px 12px 0 rgba(#000, 0.16)
        background-color white

    .video-player-comment
        flex 1

//height 23vh


:local(.container)
    .swipeable-view
        background-color #fff
        height 100%
        display flex
        flex-direction column


    .react-swipeable-view-container
        height 100%

    .info-item
        display flex
        align-items center
        padding 10px 20px
        .info-label
            flex 1
            width 100px
            font-family museo700
            font-weight 500
        .info-value
            flex 2
            font-family museo700
            font-weight 500



:local(.container)
    .tags-table
        display flex
        flex-direction column
        flex 1


    .tags-header
        display flex
        align-items center
        height 32px
        justify-content space-around
    //border-bottom 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid
        background-color rgba(#000, 0.12)
        padding-left 30px
    .header-item
        flex-grow 1
        flex-basis 0

    .tags-table-body
        flex 1
        overflow-y hidden
        max-height 600px

    .tags-table-actions
        clearfix()
        display flex
        align-items center
        justify-content flex-end
        padding 4px 12px
        height 48px

        border-top 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid

    .header-item
        padding 6px 8px

    .header-1, .header-2
    .cell-1, .cell-2
        width 80px

    .header-3, .header-4
    .cell-3, .cell-4
        flex 1

    .list-item
        display flex
        align-items center
        border-bottom 1px #eee solid
        padding-left 30px
        position relative
        &:hover, &.is-active
            background-color #f2f2f2

        &.is-active
            border 1px orange solid
            border-width 1px 0 1px 0

        .cell
            padding 2px 8px
            display flex
            align-items center
            height 50px
        &:after
            absolute top 16px left 8px
            width 16px
            height 16px
            content ''

        &.has-alcohol
            &:after
                background-color #FFDC00
        &.has-smoking
            &:after
                background-color #D13F19



    .red-box
        width 16px
        height 16px
        margin 3px 10px
        background-color red

    .yellow-box
        width 16px
        height 16px
        margin 3px 10px
        background-color yellow


:local(.container) .video-player-comment
    margin 20px 10px 50px 0px
    background-color #fff
    box-shadow 0px 4px 12px 0 rgba(#000, 0.16)
    display flex
    flex-direction column

    .textarea-comment
        border none
        border-bottom 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid
        flex 1
        resizable none
        padding 20px

    .comment-footer
        height 50px
        padding 4px 12px
        display flex
        align-items center
        justify-content flex-end


:local(.container)
    .marker-view-body
        padding 20px
        flex 1

    .marker-view-footer
        padding 0 20px
        height 50px
        text-align right
        border-top 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid

    .control
        display flex
        align-items flex-start
        width 100%
        margin-bottom 20px

    .control-label
        width 200px
        padding 15px 12px

:local(.container)
    .flags-table
        display flex
        flex-flow column
        overflow hidden
        flex 1

tbody
    overflow-y auto
    min-height 380px
thead
    display block
    flex-shrink 0

tr
    display flex
    width 100%

th,
td
    min-width 25px
    display flex

th~th,
td~td
    flex 1 1 22%
    word-wrap break-word
h4, h3{
    font-family museo700
    font-weight 500
}
.add-tag-header{
    margin-left 30px;
    margin-bottom 30px;
}

select, Select{
    border-style solid
    border-width 2px
    min-width 300px
    max-width 400px
    height 40px
    font-family museo500
    padding-left 10px
    font-size 15px
    background-color transparent
    border-color black
}
select > option {
    font-family museo500

}

.detail-div h4{
    display:inline-block;
    width:140px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom 25px
}
```